A simple betting game between two players
This is not poker, but it reminded me of poker and the more I think about it the more confused I get, even though it seems significantly simpler than poker.
The game is as follows. Two players take turns betting higher amounts until one of them stops, at which point the player who bet the most wins $100. However, both players lose the final amount they bet. The goal is to find a strategy which makes the most money.
I believe an optimal strategy will be some sort of mixed strategy similar to poker.
Some possibilities:

Always bet one cent higher than the other player. However if the other player adopts this strategy as well, your expected loses are infinite.

Always bet one cent higher than the other player until you reach $100. However the other player might adopt the strategy to always bet one cent higher until they reach $101.01, in which case you'd lose $100 and the other player would lose 1 cent.

Bet $99.99 on turn one before the opponent has bet. This way the opponent has no reason to bet, since they may win $100, but they will lose the $100 they bet netting them $0 overall. This strategy apparently makes 1 penny, but is there a better strategy?

Suppose there is an optimal strategy which makes on average X dollars per round. In this case betting above X dollars apparently loses money, since you pay more than your expected winnings, but there is reason to bet above X dollars. This is because if you don't and the opponent realizes your strategy, they will begin betting X+1 dollars.


I'd certainly appreciate help understanding this game, since it seems very fascinating being so simple yet so confusing. It seems significantly simpler than poker so I'd hope since poker seems fairly well understood with computers, this game could also be understood.

This is game theory. I'd suggest you repost on https://math.stackexchange.com/ . (You may wish to clarify the rules: in #3, it isn't obvious that the opponent has no reason to bet, since this depends on whether they are affected or motivated by the amount you will win.)
